# Check stored procedure return value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

A stored procedure is returning values like :

```
Text       Value
sdsd         555
dsaa         544
swewe        745
```

And if it fails, it's returning like :

```
Standard
No Records Fouond
```

How can I distinguish among this 2 results in SQL query level?

Note : I can not modify the stored procedure

Comment: You'll need to provide more information. How are you calling it? In what language?

Comment: its like : `EXEC usp_GetInfo '1122'`  - which is retruning the 2 types of result... the language in SQL..in sql server 2008..

Comment: Are you calling sproc in another sproc? please show some example of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

use the output of proc to find out that.

```
    IF EXISTS(
                SELECT name 
                FROM sysobjects 
                WHERE  name = N'Pr_Test' 
                AND type = 'P' )
    DROP PROCEDURE Pr_Test
    GO
    Create Procedure Pr_Test
    (
        @output BIT=0
    )
    As
    BEGIN  
    SET NOCOUNT ON  

        IF @output = 0
            SELECT 'No Records Fouond' AS [STANDARD]
        ELSE
            SELECT 'abc' AS [text], 1 AS [VALUE]

    SET NOCOUNT OFF  
    END  
    Go

    SET NOCOUNT ON
        DECLARE @ProcOutput TABLE 
        (
            column1     sysname NOT NULL
        )


        INSERT INTO @ProcOutput(Column1)
        EXEC Pr_Test

        IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM @ProcOutput WHERE column1='No Records Fouond')
            PRINT ' this is failed select from proc'
        ELSE
            PRINT 'proc has some results'
    SET NOCOUNT OFF
```